# MySQL using IN to select just those values not results including those values

Tags: mysql, sql

In my dataset, each person has several bookings. People are able to book a booking with 1 or more companies. I want to calculate booking value for customers who have booked with a specific 2 companies, but don't have any bookings with any other companies.

The way the data is stored is that each person can have several rows detailing booking value for each company.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT b.booked_date, b.price

FROM person p

LEFT JOIN booking b ON p.booking_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN company c ON b.company_id = c.id

WHERE c.name IN (company1, company2)
```

However this is just calculating the booking value of each row which contains company1 and company2. What I want to do is exclude any people who have bookings with any companies other than company1 and company2.

Comment: Your 2nd LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result, since you have the c table conditions in the WHERE clause. Move to ON to get LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id
FROM person p
  JOIN booking b ON p.booking_id = b.id
  JOIN company c ON b.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name IN (company1, company2)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)=2
```

The query returns customers who booked with exactly two specified companies.

Then the query can be used in your calculations

```
SELECT b.booked_date, b.price
FROM person p
  JOIN booking b ON p.booking_id = b.id
  JOIN (the query above) sub ON sub.id=p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

StanislavL is right. But `HAVING` works just if person has booking for both 2 companies. If condition is "one of company1 or company2" then i suppose next query (be careful, it's very slow query):

```
SELECT b.booked_date, b.price
    FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN booking b ON p.booking_id = b.id
    WHERE 
        b.id IN (
            SELECT id 
            FROM booking b1 
            WHERE 
                b1.company_id IN (company1, company2) 
                AND (
                    SELECT COUNT(id) 
                    FROM booking b2 
                    WHERE 
                        b2.id = b1.id 
                        AND b2.company_id NOT IN(company1, company2) = 0
                )
        )
```